# AVPlayerLayer inside UIScrollView Not Zooming To Center

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, avplayerlayer, pbjvision

- I have a `UIScrollView *myScrollView` which has a `UIView *videoView` that contains a `AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer`*(Actually a `PBJVideoView` if anyone is familiar)*.
- The AVPlayerLayer is set to `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect`.
- myScrollView's delegate's `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` returns `videoView`.

So if I am looking at a landscape video on a portrait oriented iPhone, it fits the video so that the width matches the iPhone and there is black at the top and bottom.

As the `zoomScale` goes above 1.0 the video **seems biased towards the right side**. Like the `anchorPoint` is maybe `(0.75,0.5)` - even though it is `(0.5,0.5)`. In other words **it zooms into a point to the right of center.** (Changing the anchor point doesn't seem to affect anything)

**Is there something with the `AVPlayerLayer` that is causing this issue? I don't have the same problem with a `UIImageView`?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had little to do with AVPlayerLayer and more to do with UIScrollView's viewForZoomingInScrollView.

I had a UIImageView that is the "preview image" that shows while the video is downloading/loading, **Both views were parented to the scroll view, then the image view was removed when the video player is ready. Because of this, the contentSize/contentOffset are off.**

**I was able to fix it by removing the videoView from the scroll view. Resetting the content offset and zoomScale to 1, then adding back in the video view.**